# Particular solution of an "almost" homogeneous first order ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am aware that the solution to a homogeneous first order differential equation of the form $\frac{dy}{dx} = p(x)y $ can be obtained by simply by rearranging to:

$\frac{dy}{y} = p(x)dx$

Then it is simply a question of integrating both sides and the answer is straightforward. Now what would happen if RHS had a constant, how a can find a particular solution to this case:
$\frac{dy}{dx} = p(x) y + C $

I know that the general solution would be the sum of the homogeneous equation and the particular solution

Comment: Is it $$\frac{dy}{dx} = p(x) + C$$

Comment: Corrected. It was $p(x) y  + C$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply rearrange :

$$\frac{dy}{dx} -yp(x) = C$$

Now multiply both the sides by $e^{\int p(x)dx}$.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}e^{\int p(x)dx} -yp(x)e^{\int p(x)dx} = Ce^{\int p(x)dx}$$
This LHS is nothing else :

$$\frac{dy}{dx}e^{\int p(x)dx} -yp(x)e^{\int p(x)dx} = \frac{d}{dx} \left(y \cdot e^{\int p(x)dx} \right)$$

Now our differential equation becomes :

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(y \cdot e^{\int p(x)dx} \right)=Ce^{\int p(x)dx} $$

Hence :

> $$ y =\frac{\displaystyle\int{Ce^{\int p(x)dx}}dx}{\displaystyle e^{\int p(x)dx}}$$

Comment: Ok so is that solution the general solution of the equation?

Comment: @daljit97 Yes. It is the only way to solve every differential equation of this form

Comment: You're missing a $dx$ on the big integral in the last equation. Since there are two integrals, may be better to be more precise and make them definite.

Comment: @Chappers Oh! Thanks. Fixed it.

Comment: It might be useful to point out that this is known as the method of integrating factor.